# Printing the current URL in React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I would like to print the URL in screen (yes it's written in the URL bar, but I would like to do it anyway)

What can I use ?
In the following example, what can I write instead of `{iDontKnowWhatToWriteHere}` to give the curent URL ?

```
import React from 'react';

class Connexion extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <h1> the URL is {iDontKnowWhatToWriteHere} </h1>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: window.location.href

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is a normal javascript library that takes care just of the view of your application, so It allows you to access all the normal browser APIs and properties availables and one of them is **location**.

So if you want to access the actual url in React you should do it in the way that you would do it without React **(Except when you're using some especific library for that problem like react-router)**, just:

If you want to get all the url (Including the domain, protocol, port)

```
window.location.href
```

Or if you just want the path after de domain

```
window.location.pathname
```

**In your code**

```
import React from 'react';

class Connexion extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <h1> the URL is {window.location.pathname} </h1>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use `React Router` you can use

```
return (
    <h1> the URL is {this.context.location.pathname} </h1>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about your url using the **window.location** object that is provided by vanilla JavaScript.

For reference, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

You could use `window.location.href` to get the full url. Attached is a screenshot of the location object (I got it from Chrome web console)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router. Try:

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

Regards